# Code for prime numbers, why only with "sqrt()"

Tags: c, primes, function-definition, sqrt

I wrote a program for finding prime numbers, my problem is that the code only will run correctly, only if I take the square root of the tested number (on the marked line).

When I have `int i = input` the code wont run.

I know that `sqrt()` is helpful here but i thought it should work without as well.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<math.h>

bool primeNumber(int input)
{
    for(int i = sqrt(input); i > 1; i--)                   // <------- sqrt()              
    {
        if(input % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    } return true;
}


int main()
{
    int input;
    printf("Pls type in a positive number: ");
    scanf("%d",&input);
    
    for(int i = input; i > 1; i--)
    {
        bool prime = primeNumber(i);
        if(prime)
        {
            printf("%d is a prime number\n",i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give sample inputs and describe what you mean by "won't run".

Comment: if you start with input -> `input % input == 0` so everything will be false, you can try `input/2` or `input-1` as a starting point if you object to sqrt

Comment: It won't run? Does the compiler give an error, or is the output faulty, or what?

Comment: `for (i = 2; i * i <= input; i++) {` is a better way to do the loop -- both for average speed, and to avoid floating point.

Comment: @PaulHankin `i * i` could overflow. `i <= input / i` won't overflow.

Comment: You can speed things up a bit by only checking for divisibility by odd numbers and by 2.

Comment: @IanAbbott nice suggestion. I thought the division might be slower than the multiplication but the difference is not measurable (with -O2 at least). Perhaps because x86 idiv gives both the quotient and remainder, and the remainder is needed anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Every positive integer has itself as a factor. A number is prime if its only factors are itself and one. If you consider a number non-prime because it has itself as a factor, then you will consider no numbers to be prime.

Answer (score 2):

For starters the function is incorrect. It returns true for example for the number equal to `1` though `1` is not a prime number. Also as the function parameter has the signed integer type `int` then the user can pass to the function a negative number.

Also you should write a more general function that can work with any unsigned integer type.

As for your question

> When I have int i = input the code wont run.

then each number is divisible by itself.

The function can be more efficient and written without using the function `sqrt`. Except the even number `2` all other prime numbers are odd. So there is no sense to check whether an even number except `2` is a prime number.

```
bool primeNumber( unsigned long long int input )
{
    bool prime = number % 2 == 0 ? number == 2 : number != 1;

    for ( unsigned long long int i = 3; prime && i <= number / i; i += 2 )
    {
        prime = number % i != 0;
    }

    return prime;     
}
```

And in main you should write

```
unsigned int input;

printf( "Pls type in a non-negative number: ");
scanf("%u",&input);

for( unsigned int i = input; i > 0; i-- )
{
    bool prime = primeNumber(i);
    if(prime)
    {
        printf("%u is a prime number\n",i);
    }
}
```